# Using ASP.NET validators on multiple controls

Tags: asp.net

can we use the same validator of a control for two different buttons,
or do we need to write add a validator for each control for two different buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Each ASP.NET validator control can be bound to exactly one `ControlToValidate`, except for the `CompareValidator`. The `CompareValidator` also has a `ControlToCompare` property. You need to add a validator for each control you wish to validate.

When you find that your markup gets bloated with validators, you can also create a handy extension methods on `Control` and let it automaticaly add a new validator to the page. You can invoke this method in your code behind in `OnPreInit` or `OnInit`.